# How can the font Open Baskerville be used with plain TeX?

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

I downloaded the font Open Baskerville from [here](http://klepas.org/openbaskerville/), but I don't know how to use it.  How can it be loaded in plain TeX?  I can use any of `tex`, `pdftex` or `xetex`.  (I am using `texlive` on Linux.)

Comment: You can, with XeTeX; however it appears that the OTF font has no features nor ligatures defined (although it seems to have the glyphs for the f-ligatures). There's no italic font and so I don't think it's really usable yet.

Comment: you may fake italics with slanted, and fake poor man's boldface; they may be usable, but most of them fake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program `otfinfo` shows no feature in the OTF font file, which makes it pretty unusable with XeTeX unless a mapping file is prepared for adding f-ligatures or other ones.

However, the distribution comes with a `features.fea` file that allows to get ligatures with LuaTeX.

I unzipped the downloaded archive and moved to the created directory; I changed the name of

```
OpenBaskerville-0.0.75.otf
```

into the more sensible `OpenBaskerville.otf`; then I moved the file `features.fea` from the folder `OpenBaskerville-0.0.75.ufo` into the working directory, renaming it to `OpenBaskerville.fea`.

Finally I prepared the following file

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\OBx="[OpenBaskerville.otf]":featurefile=OpenBaskerville.fea;+liga
\font\OBxS="[OpenBaskerville.otf]":featurefile=OpenBaskerville.fea;+liga;+dlig;+swsh
\font\OBxviii="[OpenBaskerville.otf]":featurefile=OpenBaskerville.fea;+liga at 18pt

\OBx

{\OBxviii A section title}

\medskip

Ligatures such as firefly and flagstaff
but not gictast

\OBxS

Ligatures such as firefly and flagstaff
but also gictast

\bye
```

and processed it with `luatex`, obtaining

[image]

Unfortunately the font seems to be at a very preliminary stage and has no italic companion font. Artificially slanting it would be a sin against the memory of Baskerville and his beautiful italic fonts.